# Porting HTML5 Canvas.arc to Android and counterclockwise

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I'm porting [Skycons](http://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/) to Android and I've got most of them working, except the moon uses HTML5's `Canvas.arc` with the counterclockwise argument.

I've tried to implement this like so:

```
RectF rect = new RectF();

public void arcR( Path path, float x, float y, float radius, double startAngle, double endAngle, boolean anticlockwise ){
    // Set bounds
    rect.set( x - radius, y - radius, x + radius, y + radius );

    // Convert to degrees
    startAngle = Math.toDegrees(startAngle);
    endAngle = Math.toDegrees(endAngle);

    if(anticlockwise){
        startAngle = 360 - startAngle;
        endAngle = 360 - endAngle;
    }

    endAngle = endAngle - startAngle;

    path.addArc(rect, (float)startAngle, (float)endAngle);
}
```

I don't think I've implemented counterclockwise correctly, as on my device drawing the moon (based on Skycons) looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: there is no notion of clockwise and counter clock wise in android canvas because the sign of the sweep angle defines if it is clockwise or counter clockwise.

Comment: @njzk2 I am aware of that, but HTML5 does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For counter clockwise arcs, the sweep angle needs to be negative

```
float sweepAngle = ((endAngle + 360) - startAngle) % 360;
if (anticlockwise) {
  sweepAngle = sweepAngle - 360;
}
path.addArc(rect, startAngle, sweepAngle);
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
double sweepAngle = endAngle - startAngle;
startAngle = 360 - endAngle;
path.addArc(rect, (float)startAngle, (float)sweepAngle);
```

Comment: No dice. I can't seem to make the graphics work in the right way. It's working partially, except the moon appears at the wrong end :G

Comment: The code I posted are for drawing counterClockwise from startAngle to endAngle using path.addArc. I have assumed `(endAngle > startAngle) && (endAngle == endAngle % 360) && (startAngle == startAngle % 360)` It works in my test.  
  
When you say "in the right way", what exactly do you mean. Perhaps I'd be able to help you if you supplied more details.

Comment: I'm trying to port Skycons which draws everything frame-by-frame in a HTML5 canvas and I don't have a clue how it generates the angles for the moon icon.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [source](https://github.com/darkskyapp/skycons/blob/master/skycons.js#L223)?

Comment: Yes except it's not very well documented

Answer (score 0):

To draw a cutout line like that you need to find the center of the second circle. I've assumed that the cutout circle radius would be the same as in the original circle, but of course you can change that.

Please try this code:

```
private void drawMoon(Path path, float x, float y, float radius, float startAngle, float endAngle) {

  float sweepAngle = endAngle - startAngle;

  float x1 = (float) (x + radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(startAngle)));
  float y1 = (float) (y + radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(startAngle)));

  float x2 = (float) (x + radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(endAngle)));
  float y2 = (float) (y + radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(endAngle)));

  float x3 = (x1 + x2) / 2;
  float y3 = (y1 + y2) / 2;
  float q = (float) Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));

  float r = radius; // cutout circle radius
  float cx = (float) (x3 + Math.sqrt(r * r - (q / 2) * (q / 2)) * (y1 - y2) / q);
  float cy = (float) (y3 + Math.sqrt(r * r - (q / 2) * (q / 2)) * (x2 - x1) / q);

  path.rewind();

  rect.set(x - radius, y - radius, x + radius, y + radius);
  path.addArc(rect, startAngle, sweepAngle);

  rect.set(cx - r, cy - r, cx + r, cy + r);
  path.addArc(rect, (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y1 - cy, x1 - cx)), 360 - sweepAngle);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

differences between html5 canvas arc and android canvas arc:

1. in html5/javascript you give centerX, centerY, radius as first 3 arguments. In android, you give the rectangle enclosing the circle instead of those 3. That is a little more cumbersome for circles, but is more flexible, as you can then also do ovals (ellipse)
2. in javascript, you give start angle, end angle, and boolean for counterclockwise as arguments 4,5,6. In android, you give instead start angle and "sweep angle". The "sweep angle" is the difference between end angle and start angle. If you want counterclockwise, just give a negative sweep angle.
3. javascript angles are in radians, and in android they are in degrees.

As an illustration, here is some example code which draws a C - shaped figure consisting of a long arc on the left, and 3 short arcs on the right, one of which is counterclockwise.

JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
        <title>arcs</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function initPage(){
    ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    pi = Math.PI;
    r = 100;
    R = 3 * r;
    padding = 5;
    width = 2 * (R + padding);
    height = width;
    centerX = padding + width/2;
    centerY = padding + height/2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY,       R,   pi/2, 3*pi/2, false);
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY - 2*r, r, 3*pi/2,   pi/2, false);
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY,       r, 3*pi/2,   pi/2, true );
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY + 2*r, r, 3*pi/2,   pi/2, false);
    ctx.fill();
}
        </script>        
    </head>

    <body onload="initPage();">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="610" height="610"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

android:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private void drawToImageView(ImageView iv){
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Path path = new Path();
        int radius = 140;
        int Radius = 3 * radius;
        int padding = 5;
        int width = 2 * (Radius + padding);
        int height = width;
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
        float a = 90f;
        float b = 3*a;
        float pi = 2*a;
        float _radius = (float)radius;
        float _Radius = (float)Radius;
        float centerX = padding + width/2;
        float centerY = padding + height/2;
        path.addArc(circRect(centerX, centerY,             _Radius), a,  pi);
        path.addArc(circRect(centerX, centerY - 2*_radius, _radius), b,  pi);
        path.addArc(circRect(centerX, centerY,             _radius), b, -pi);
        path.addArc(circRect(centerX, centerY + 2*_radius, _radius), b,  pi);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        iv.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm));
    }
    private RectF circRect(float centerX, float centerY, float radius){
        float left   = centerX - radius;
        float right  = centerX + radius;
        float top    = centerY - radius;
        float bottom = centerY + radius;
        return new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        drawToImageView(iv);
    }
}
```